# Heroku Data Clip cannot be created

Tags: php, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-postgres

I am trying to create tables in heroku postgre database. I am recieving the following error

```
Error: Dataclip cannot be created

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE "users" (
```

This is my query

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
  "userid" integer SERIAL NOT NULL ,
  "fname" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "lname" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  "password" varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  "email_address" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("userid"),
  UNIQUE KEY "email_address" ("email_address")
) ;
```

I have searched all over internet but couldn't anything useful.If you need more detail please ask me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "integer" from line 2. Serial is in fact auto-increment integer in postgresql.